# How do you pass a variable with the method name to @selector()?

Tags: objective-c, selector

I need to pass a method name to @selector(method) inside a loop where the method is a value contained in an array.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(method:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

How can I define a @selector() inside a loop an avoid having to hard code each @selector(method)? Can I pass in a string value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either [`NSSelectorFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString), which maps an `NSString` to a `SEL`, or you can use [`sel_registerName()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/sel_registerName), which maps a `char*` to a `SEL`.